# TFS2012: Move changesets (with history) to a new branch

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I recently introduced TFS to a project team that had not been using version control. Our structure is pretty simple:

- MAIN branch for production-ready code
- DEV branch for (complete) test-ready code
- Feature branches for incomplete code not ready for testing

As I said, this team is not used to using version control. Over the holidays a well-motivated team member decided he would try to work on a feature, however he did this directly in DEV and made a number of check-ins. His feature is not complete so I don't want it polluting DEV for now, but I don't want to lose the history of changesets.

The obvious way is to make a new branch off the last changeset before his feature, merge the rest to the new branch, and rollback DEV. However, I'm afraid I'll lose the history of changes and be left with just a single "merge" changeset in the new branch.

If this is the case, is there a way to simply move all the changesets after a certain changeset into a new branch and keep the history?

EDIT: Basically I want to turn this:

```
DEV ---(1)--(2)--(3)--(4)--(5)--(6)--
```

into this:

```
DEV ---(1)--(2)--(3)----------------
                    \
               NEW   (4)--(5)--(6)--
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not supported in TFVC ( nor any other SVCS). If you were using Git is TFS there would be hope, but not here. Your suggested solution is your only avenue.

Comment: That's disappointing, it's so easy to do this in git. It seems like a pretty useful feature to leave out...  So everything will get squashed to a single commit if I do it this way, correct?

Comment: It's not "left out" this is in fact a characteristic of all server based source control systems and you will see the same in Perforce, Subversion, and any other linear system. I would recommend that you move your code to a new Team Project created with Git in TFS...